# SDK levels for lollipop

Tags: android, sdk, version

what are the best apk level to run a app in a android lollipop 5.1 version. Here is what I currently having

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.locationtracker2019"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: APK level? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

As per your Question your application is running in the `minSdkVersion` means that your minimum version support your app.

`targetSdkVersion` is the main way Android provide forward compatibility not applying behavior change unless the targetSdkVersion is update.

It should be emphasized that changing your `compileSdkVersion` does not change runtime behavior. While new compiler errors/warnings may present when chang your compileSdkVersion, your compileSdkVersion is not included in your APK: it is purely used at compile time.

For more information about, [What is API Level?](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels)

I hope it'll help you...!